# What is the key to generate aeg-sas-token

Tags: azure-eventgrid

EventGrid Doc provides a sample code to generate aeg-sas-token. However, I could not find what is the key used to generate aeg-sas-token. I tried the EventGrid access key and it did not work.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of what you are doing?

Comment: try to use a min time 8 minutes, so the expirationUtc = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(8). For me it' is working very well.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. According to [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/security-authentication#sas-tokens), the resource is: `https://<yourtopic>.<region>.eventgrid.azure.net/eventGrid/api/events`. However, the actual resource that works for me is: `https://<yourtopic>.<region>.eventgrid.azure.net/eventGrid/api/events?api-version=2018-01-01`